# BroadCast Receiver Not triggering(Only when device restart)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I created one custom receiver inside Activity for when internet is connected auto calling web service.Its working fine but i have faced issue in below scenario.

1. Turn off my internet connectivity.
2. restart my device.
3. Open my application.

That time is not calling OnReceive function.

Code Like Below

```
 private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
            if (!noConnectivity) {
                bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                callAuthorizeWebservice();
            } else {
                bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Check Your Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
```

And

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }
```

Kindly help me to solve this issue

Comment: can you post your AndroidManifest.xml ? Looks like something missing there

Comment: @Ramesh Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are not `registering` your `BroadcastReceiver` programatically.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
  filter.addAction("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED");
  filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
     registerReceiver(mConnReceiver , filter);
```

The receivers created programatically need to be registered programatically. If you create programatically and enters entry in `AndroidManifest`, then it will not be fired.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have mention this

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }

Comment: But when activity is destroyed at that time i unregistered the receiver like

 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(mConnReceiver);
    }

Comment: Then you should not create `Inner Class` of `BroadcastReceiver`. Create separate class and then in `AndroidManifest.xml` set the intentfilter there. Keep this code as it is but create the separate class for boot completion receiver because you can not receive boot completion if you register programatically

Comment: If i creating the separate  BroadcastReceiver then how to unregistered the receiver(when app is closed)

Comment: Just like now you are doing. Create the instance of that class, register in onStart, unregister in onDestroy

Answer (score 0):

Add below permission in manifest to receive Boot completed event.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Register a receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now define `MyBroadcastReceiver` -

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
    if (!noConnectivity) {
        bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        callAuthorizeWebservice();
    } else {
        bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Check Your Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, AndroidManifest.xml  missing permission entries <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 ?